# Material-UI DataGrid, display sum of column and sum updates according to filter as well

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I have this Material-UI DataGrid, how can I sum all of the values for the column Total Amount in which this will also be updated once filter is triggerd as well?

I am really unsure on how I can sum the entire column of total amount. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Codes:

```
  const [filterModel, setFilterModel] = React.useState({
    items: [
      {
        columnField: "totalAmount",
        operatorValue: ">",
        value: "200"
      }
    ]
  });

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid
        // rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        rows={data}
        components={{
          Toolbar: GridToolbar
        }}
        filterModel={filterModel}
        onFilterModelChange={(newFilterModel) => setFilterModel(newFilterModel)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create custom footer component, and then pass `total` value as a prop.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/controlledfilters-material-demo-sample-forked-jzbf7x?file=/demo.js) I created sandbox with complete solution.

Comment: Thank you. But how does the sum of the total amount display based on filter as well?

Comment: Hello @Nemanja Do you know as well about  Mui-datatable where it has this similar functions where it displays the sum of the entire column? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71448488/mui-datatable-how-can-i-display-the-sum-of-the-entire-column

Comment: @PennieCorhon You're welcome. In the documentation of the MUI datatable (https://mui.com/api/data-grid/data-grid/)  API I do not see that there is an build in option to summarize the columns. You need to write that logic manually.